# Query a subset of results, subquery syntax?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm looking for assistance with a query that I can't seem to get past errors with.

I have two tables, one of instances, and one of operational groups. Each operational group contains the instances, so I'd have:

```
Groups.(ID, Verified (Y/N))
Instances.(ID, source (A/B/C/D), status (X/Y/Z, groupid)
```

The first thing I need to do is isolate only the groups which contain instances with `source=A` and then I need to count the total instances with `source != A` and `status = Z`.

The problem is, I haven't been able to figure out where to put the subquery without generating an error. I tried putting it as an alias'd subtable in FROM but that didn't seem to work

Here's the basic query I had come up with that's not working:

```
SELECT COUNT(Instances.id)
FROM (
    SELECT Instances.id
    JOIN Groups ON Instances.groupid=Groups.id
    WHERE Groups.Verified='Y' AND Instances.source='A') AS a
WHERE Groups.Verified='Y' AND Instances.source!='A' AND Instances.status='Z';
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks! I'm quite new to SQL and have had no formal training but am in an enviornment where I need to use it regularly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gives you the ids of all groups that have at least one instance with `source = 'A'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(groupid) FROM Instances WHERE source = 'A'
```

Building up from this, you need to again query `Instances`, taking into account only those records that belong to one of the above groups with

```
WHERE groupid IN (SELECT DISTINCT(groupid) FROM Instances WHERE source = 'A')
      AND source != 'A' AND status = 'Z'
```

And you also need to `GROUP BY groupid` so that this query will give you a count of matching instances for each group separately. So the final query becomes

```
SELECT groupid, COUNT(*) AS instance_count FROM Instances
WHERE groupid IN (SELECT DISTINCT(groupid) FROM Instances WHERE source = 'A')
      AND source != 'A' AND status = 'Z'
GROUP BY groupid
```

Comment: Running the query now, seems to be running a long time, but the database is large, will let you know how it comes out, thanks!

Comment: The sytax looks right but I'm not getting a result after 10 minutes so that's something on the database end the team is going to look at for me, thanks for the assist!